# How to use setInterval and clearInterval in Vue.js 3?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3

I'm writing an application which uses a timer to update variables every second. It uses "setInterval" function to start the timer, and uses "clearInterval" function to stop it. And I don't think I have a good enough way of doing this.

I tried to define the timer as a ref variable in setup function, and clear the timer in the "onUnmounted" lifecycle hook, like the example code below:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onUnmounted } from "vue";

const timer = ref(setInterval(() => {/* Bla bla bla. */}, 1000));

onUnmounted(() => {
  clearInterval(timer.value);
})
<script>
```

But I don't think it would be necessary to make the timer reactive, is there a better way of doing this? Or is my code a good method?

Comment: Just use a variable, no ref. The use of async side effects in the body of setup is incompatible with SSR, better to use onMounted

Comment: Yes, you are right. I also thought of this, and I'm not sure whether it will work. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is a good way to handle timers in a Vue application. However, as you mentioned, making the timer reactive is not necessary in this case. Instead, you can directly assign the timer ID to a variable. Here's an example of how you can improve your code:

```
    <script setup lang="ts">
import { onUnmounted } from "vue";

let timerId = setInterval(() => {
  // Your code here
  console.log("Timer is running...");
}, 1000);

onUnmounted(() => {
  clearInterval(timerId);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use libs, use libs
https://vueuse.org/shared/useIntervalFn/

```
import { useIntervalFn } from '@vueuse/core'

const { pause, resume, isActive } = useIntervalFn(() => {
  /* your function */
}, 1000)
```

Otherwise, make a composable

```
function useIntervalFn(cb: () => void, ms: number) {
   let int: number = 0;
   onMounted(() => int = setInterval(cb, ms));
   onUnmounted(() => clearInterval(int));
}
```